# duplicate value textefield in listView in wicket

Tags: listview, model, wicket, textfield

I have to display in a form  a set of textfield repeated a number of times as below

- Column1    Column2     column3

  ---
- TextField1   TextField2   TextField3
- TextField1   TextField2    TextField3
- TextField1   TextField2    TextField3

the problem is that when I try to get the values filled by the user from the model ,  I always get the values of the last line at all lines. 
Can you please tell me why i get all the time the last line ?

Code :

// initialize model

```
ArrayList<Model<line>> model= new ArrayList<Model<line>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < demande.getQuantite(); i++) {            
            list.add(i,new Model<Line>());

        }
```

// ListView

```
      add(new ListView("infoCollectListView", rowsCount) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {            
                    for(InfoCollecte collecte : infosCollects){

                        String columnValue = "column"+collecte.getOrdre() ;

                        TextField<String> textField = new TextField<String>(collecte.getCodeInfo(),new PropertyModel<String>(model.get(item.getIndex()), columnValue));
    item.add(textField);

                    }

            }

           });
```

// line object

```
public class LigneInfoCollect implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private InfoCollecte  column0;
private InfoCollecte  column1;
private InfoCollecte  column2;
private InfoCollecte  column3;
private InfoCollecte  column4;
private InfoCollecte  column5;
private InfoCollecte  column6;
private InfoCollecte  column7;
private InfoCollecte  column8;
private InfoCollecte  column9;
private InfoCollecte  column10;
private InfoCollecte  column11;
private InfoCollecte  column12;
private InfoCollecte  column13;
private InfoCollecte  column14;
private InfoCollecte  column15;
private InfoCollecte  column16;
private InfoCollecte  column17;
private InfoCollecte  column18;
private InfoCollecte  column19;
private InfoCollecte  column20;
private InfoCollecte  column21;
private InfoCollecte  column22;
private InfoCollecte  column23;
private InfoCollecte  column24;
private InfoCollecte  column25;
private InfoCollecte  column26;

private int index;
 }
```

// List view HTML

```
<span wicket:id="infoCollectListView">
                        <tr>

                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_ACCESSOIRE" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_ALWAYS" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_ANSWER_EXTERNAL" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_ANSWER_INTERNAL" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_BUSY_EXTERNAL" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_BUSY_INTERNAL" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_LOGIN" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_MAIL" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><select wicket:id="INFO_MESS_VOCAL"/></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_MIVOICE_FOR_LYNC" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_NOM" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_NUM_ASSO" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_NUM_GRP" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_NUM_INTERNE" type="text" size="20" /></td>
                            <td><input wicket:id="INFO_NUM_LIGNE" type="text" size="20" /></td>
```

// Get texte field values

```
 Button buttonSuivant = new Button("buttonSuivant", new Model<String>(this.getString("submitQuote_button_next"))) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
            try{

                 ArrayList<Model<Line>> s = model;


    };
```

Comment: You've got a little confused over how ListView works in terms of its use of the supporting model. Have a look at some of the examples on the Wicket website.

Comment: Can you tell me please what wrong with using my model in Listview ? i didn't find in wicket examples how to do it ?

Comment: You shouldn't really need to have a for loop iteration in your populateItem method. Look here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/ListView+and+other+repeaters

Comment: to summarize my problem is that in general way when I add a textfield to a list view, when I try to retrieve the value of a textfield I always get the value of the last field in all fields . I didn't success to find how to fix this problem , i sent more than 2 days but i didn't find the solution , can you help me please !!